# Reverse of a list of list in Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to horizontally reverse the matrix in Python.

```
input 1 0
      1 0

output 0 1
       0 1
```

Here is the code...

```
class Reversedmat(object):
    def __list_oflist__(self,mat)
        rows = len(mat)
        columns = len(mat[0])
        for i in range(0, len(mat)):
            reversed_mat = ""
            for j in range(0, len(mat[i])):
                reversed_mat += str(mat[i][j]) + "\t" ## this is where im
            print(reverse(reversed_mat))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mat =[[1,0],[1,0]]
    print(Reversedmat().__list_oflist__(mat))
```

I have been trying to do this in Python, but I was not able to achieve. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code properly. We can't read Python that isn't indented properly. You can use the code button in the editor.

Comment: In Python there can be functions without classes and the names enclosed in double underscores have special meanings by convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
def reversemat(mat):
    return [row[::-1] for row in mat]
print(reversemat([[1,0],[1,0]]))
# [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

besides, you have returned nothing from your function, so you will get None from your second print.

Comment: This code did worked for me, but on my code if i add print(reverse(reversed_mat[::-1] + "\n")) and execute ill be getting the output, but i was confused, what would be a best approach to get this done. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sun_deep `[::-1]` returns a reversed list. Your original code is a bit tedious, so would be good to use `[::-1]` for simplicity.

Comment: Kevin Fang, Thanks for the details, i have been think in a wrong way. Thanks for the info